# Turning off paypal as a payment option in woocommerce 4.5.2

Tags: woocommerce, paypal

I have a woocommerce site and do not want paypal as a payment option. How do i turn that off? Am using stripe for payments.

Answer (score 0):

You’ll find the setting under **WooCommerce > Settings > Payments > PayPal** – you will have to uncheck the **Enable/Disable** checkbox.